# What is causing this AttributeError?

Tags: python, pygame, attributeerror

I've been looking all over for a solution but haven't found one so here's my code:

```
class snakeGame:
    def _init_(self):
        pygame.init()
        self._isRunning = False
        self._surface = None
        self.drawList = None
        self.updateList = None
        self.resources = loadResources()
        self.width = 640 
        self.height = 400
        self.size = [self.width,self.height]

    def run(self,args):
        self._surface = pygame.display.set_mode(self.size,pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
        self._isRunning = True
```

when the "run" method is called python throws an AttributeError telling me that the instance of snakeGame has no attribute "size"

i'm pretty new to python and have NNNOOO clue why it doesn't see it. Can someone help me?

also this is only a small snippet from the my code. If you need more, please ask. I just figured the problem was probably in here somewhere.

Answer (score 14):

You need two underscores before and after the init function: `__init__`.  `_init_` has no special meaning and isn't being called when your object is constructed.

Comment: holy cow. that is kinda embarrassing. thanks a million nathan :) I sorta knew it would be something like that but still... holy cow lol

Comment: I take it that I answered your question?  (Of course neither comment of ours really belong here.  You should accept this answer and we should both just delete our comments.)